# Sum all same elements in one array

Tags: javascript, arrays

how can I sum all same elements in one array? For example I have an array:

```
  [20,20,20,10,10,5,1]
```

How can I make it `[60,20,5,1]`?

Here's what I have tried so far:

```
var money = [20, 20, 20, 10, 10, 5, 1];
for (var i = 0; i < money.length; i++) {
  if (money[i] == money[i + 1]) {
    money[i] += money[i + 1];
    money.splice(money.indexOf(money[i + 1]), 1);
  }
}
```

Comment: What did you try ?

Comment: Are you guaranteed that the duplicates will be together?

Comment: for(var i = 0; i<money.length; i++){
     if(money[i] == money[i+1]){
       money[i]+=money[i+1];
       money.splice(money.indexOf(money[i+1]),1);
     }
  }

Comment: this was my code, but it works just for two  elemetns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method with a variable to store previous element.

```js
var arr = [20, 20, 20, 10, 10, 5, 1];
// variable for storing previous element
var prev;

var res = arr.reduce(function(arr, v) {
  // if element is same as previous then add 
  // value with last element
  if (prev == v)
    arr[arr.length - 1] += v;
  // else push and update prev variable
  else
    arr.push(prev = v)
    // return the array refernece
  return arr;
  // set initial value as empty array for result
}, [])

console.log(res);
```

---

**UPDATE :** If same values are not adjacent then use an object to refer the index.

```js
var arr = [20, 20, 20, 10, 10, 5, 1];
// object for refering index
var ref = {};

var res = arr.reduce(function(arr, v) {
  // check property is defined or not if 
  // defined update value at the index
  if (ref.hasOwnProperty(v))
    arr[ref[v]] += v;
  else {
    // else add property to object and push element
    ref[v] = arr.length;
    arr.push(prev = v)
  }
  // return array reference
  return arr;
  // set initial value as empty array for result
}, [])

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 4):

I would do something like this:

1. Count the occurrences.
2. Multiply the value with the occurrences.

**Snippet**

```js
// Our original array.
var arr = [20, 20, 20, 10, 10, 5, 1];
// Let's have a counts object that stores the counts.
var counts = {};

// Loop through the array to get the counts.
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  var num = arr[i];
  counts[num] = counts[num] ? counts[num] + 1 : 1;
}

// Have a final array.
var fin = [];
// Multiply the count with the values and push it to the final array.
for (var count in counts) {
  fin.push(counts[count] * count);
}

console.log(fin);
```

Comment: @Mahi Why can't you see the comments? Which one you don't understand?

Comment: thanks for the answer but i am a pretty young developer.. i don't anderstand this part counts[num] = counts[num] ? counts[num] + 1 : 1;

Comment: @H.Dervic same.

Comment: @H.Dervic That part I was about to explain. So, what happens there is, in the counts object, I am either setting the value to 1, if it doesn't exists or incrementing it, if it already exists. **Sorry, I forgot to document that line.**

Comment: @Mahi Sorry mate. See the above comment. ^

Comment: @H.Dervic It's a [ternary operation.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) If `counts[num]` is a "truthy" value, set `counts[num] = counts[num] + 1`. Otherwise, set it to `1`.

Comment: @MikeC Thanks for the comment mate.

Comment: @MikeC when it's truthy ? first time  it is falsy ??

Comment: @Mahi When the value is already present, it is truthy, if not it is falsy.

Comment: @Mahi Right. Any value can be interpreted as a "true" boolean value or a "false" boolean value. Those which are interpreted as "true" values are [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy). By default, `counts[num]` will be `undefined`, which is a "falsy" value. That means the very first value you put in `counts[num]` will be `1`. After that, this adds one to that value. `1` then `2` then `3` etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
var list= [20,20,20,10,10,5,1];
var result=[];
//index of already added values
var listOfIndex=[];
for(var i=0;i<list.length;i++){ 
if(listOfIndex.indexOf(i)>=0){
   continue;
}
var number=list[i];
for(var j=i+1;j<list.length;j++){ 
if(list[i]==list[j]){       
   number = number+list[j];
   listOfIndex.push(j);//push in this list the index of the value that has been added
  }
 }
 result.push(number);
}
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a hash table and store the index of the result slot. This works for unsorted values as well.

```js
var data = [20, 20, 20, 10, 10, 5, 1],
    result = [];

data.forEach(function (a) {
    if (!(a in this)) {
        this[a] = result.push(0) - 1;
    }
    result[this[a]] += a;
}, Object.create(null));
 
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another single-loop proposal using `Array.prototype.reduce` and a `hash table` that store the indices the result array being created - will handle input that is not sorted too.

See demo below:

```js
var array = [20, 20, 20, 10, 10, 5, 1];

var result = array.reduce(function(hash){
  return function(p,c) {
    if(c in hash) {
      p[hash[c]] += c;
    } else {
      // store indices in the array
      hash[c] = p.push(c) - 1;
    }
    return p;
  };
}(Object.create(null)),[]);

console.log(result);
```